# Objective C 'target action' in .m and 'outlet' in .h

Tags: objective-c, ios, cs193p

I'm currently taking the Stanford CS193p iPhone and iPad application development course ( http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255 ) and in the second lecture I got stumped when he connected the buttons of the calculator to the .m file, he connected the display label (that shows the value on the calculator) to the .h file...

My understanding of the whole implementation and header file thing was that you declare the class members in header and say what they do in the implementation, which is why this doesn't make sense to me...

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in Objective-C for a `.m` file to contain methods for a class that the `.h` file for the class doesn't declare.  In fact with the Categories feature of the language there can be more than one `.h` and `.m` that define all the methods for a class.

As far as what can be connected, the keyword `IBOutlet` marks properties or variables and `IBAction` marks action methods.  These are just hints for the editor; all of the "connections" are set up at runtime automatically.

Comment: is there any reason as to why you would put it in one as apposed to the other? I'm pretty new to programming (i've only taken a few classes at school) so a basic explanation would really help, thanks a lot for the reply!

Comment: Many methods only exist to aid the implementation so they're not useful to show in the header.  Methods that are entirely private are often listed in a category at the top of a `.m` (e.g. `@interface MyClass (MyClassInternal) ...`) so that they can still be called without warnings even though they're not mentioned in the header.  In my code I also don't show a method in the `.h` if it's called automatically (e.g. `dealloc`; any method that is only defined in order to conform to a protocol; any method that is only used by a callback scheme such as `NSNotificationCenter`).

Comment: Okay this is starting to make more sense, i actually didn't do that good of a job explaining my situation...

In the podcast they dragged a UILabel (a text label) to the .h file and a IBAction (a button) to the .m file, could it be that they didn't bring them both to the .h file because the button will be sending values (what number value button was pressed [this is a RPN calculator program]) and the label will just be showing the value of the calculations?

Comment: One thing that is *required* in the main interface for the class is the data that is stored, and by extension any properties.  In this case, the `UILabel*` would have to be remembered somewhere so it must be a field and/or property, in the header (`.h`).  Action methods, on the other hand, are just code; they are typically called only by user interface elements (not by ordinary program code) so they don't really have to be available in the `.h` for anyone else to use.  I assume this is why they needed to drag to the `.m` to associate the button with the action.